# Ionic Photo Capture & Crop

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a basic ionic application, i'd like the app to take a photo of the user, and the user can then crop the taken photo to a passport sized photo.

Does anybody know how I can achieve such a thing? I've tried jrcrop but for the life of me I can't get it working.

Comment: If you use JCrop you will just get coordination X Y, width, height,  eventually you need use back-end server side or native code to crop the image according to given coordination

Comment: Is there not a way to crop the photo in the app and send the photo in a base64 format to the server to save?

Comment: you can try the solution from this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972433/how-to-take-pictures-and-crop-them-using-ionic-framework-and-cordovacamera-plugi/36012717#36012717)

Answer (score 1):

For my Ionic app, I used a combination of [ng-flow](http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/) for the upload (on the `flow-file-added`, validate the file is OK (met file extension/upload requirements etc.)) then initiated an instance of [ngCropper](https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper) to perform the cropping. Once cropping is complete, initiated the `flow.upload()` on the flowjs object to perform the upload.

It's not possible to provide all my code to this solution, but the real stitching to make this happen occurs after cropping is:

1. First, retrieve the data URL of the cropped canvas, via a command like `var dataUrl = this.$cropCanvas.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL();`
2. Create a blob from it, [something like this JS function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171044/41211) works well.
3. Remove the original queued upload file (the full image)
4. Replace it with the *cropped* blob
5. Upload.

The replace and upload technique looks like this:

```
var theBlob = that.dataURLToBlob(dataUrl);
theBlob.name = Utility.generateGuid() + '.jpg'; // give it a new name if you like
// Remove existing image which was added to flow files cache on image dialog select
$scope.flowTileObj.flow.removeFile($scope.flowTileObj.flow.files[0]);
$scope.flowTileObj.flow.addFile(theBlob);
// Perform upload
$scope.flowTileObj.flow.upload();
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

U need to add this plugin

```
bower install --save ngCordova
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
ionic platform add ios
```

And use this code

```
<img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{urlForImage(image)}}" height="200px"/>

   $scope.addImage = function() {
            var options = {
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, // Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            allowEdit : false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        };
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            onImageSuccess(imageData);

            function onImageSuccess(fileURI) {
                createFileEntry(fileURI);
            }

            function createFileEntry(fileURI) {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, copyFile, fail);
            }
            function copyFile(fileEntry) {
                var name = fileEntry.fullPath.substr(fileEntry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                var newName = makeid() + name;

                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem2) {
                    fileEntry.copyTo(
                        fileSystem2,
                        newName,
                        onCopySuccess,
                        fail
                    );
                },
                fail);
            }
            function onCopySuccess(entry) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.images.push(entry.nativeURL);
                });
            }

            function fail(error) {
                console.log("fail: " + error.code);
            }

            function makeid() {
                var text = "";
                var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

                for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
                    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
                }
                return text;
            }

        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, will this allow the user to take a photo and crop?